# React Router 6.4 "CreateBrowserRouter" Child Element don't show

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently trying to implement React Router inside my app, I wanted to use the last version (6.4) with a Layout on all pages, so I use createBrowserRouter with my Layout element and all children to make different routes, but actually I can't see any of them with my code.

I would like to get the layout on every page, with conditional rendering depending navigation, so I must put it inside the router.

I tried to follow the doc (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) , nest routes with children item :

Router component :

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <Layout />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                element: <Dashboard />,
            },
            {
                path: 'gestion_preferences',
                element: <ManagePreferences />,
            },
            {
                path: 'trame_preferences',
                element: <ManageTrames />,
            },
        ],
    },
])
```

Layout component :

```
const Layout = () => {

  return (
        <Container
            sx={{ height: '100%' }}
            maxWidth={false}
            disableGutters={true}
        >
            <Header  />
            <Box
                sx={{
                 height: "100%",
                  overflowY: "auto",
                  display: 'flex',
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  bgcolor: 'background.main',
                  zIndex:1,
                }}
            >
                <Outlet />
            </Box>
            <Footer />
        </Container>
  )
}
```

App component :

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(routesConfig)

const App = () => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <UserProvider>
                    <Layout>
                        <RouterProvider router={router} />
                    </Layout>
                </UserProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

I don't want to repeeat the  Element inside all my components by hand

Edit :  I add others components working together, I also tried in my layout to put {children} instead of Outlet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

From what I can tell of your code examples the issue is that the `Layout` component is being rendered in two places. Once correctly as a layout route where the nested routes can render their `element` into the `Outlet` rendered by `Layout`, and again in the `App` component wrapping the `RouterProvider` component. The issue is that `Layout` doesn't consume and render any `children` prop, so the wrapped `RouterProvider` isn't rendered.

Layout

```
const Layout = () => { // <-- no children prop
  return (
    <Container
      sx={{ height: '100%' }}
      maxWidth={false}
      disableGutters={true}
    >
      <Header />
      <Box ....>
        <Outlet />
      </Box>
      <Footer />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

App

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(routesConfig);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <UserProvider>
        <Layout>
          <RouterProvider router={router} /> // <-- child of Layout
        </Layout>
      </UserProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

## Solution

The `BrowswerRouter` data router is already rendering the `Layout` component, so it's completely unnecessary in the `App` component and should be removed.

App

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(routesConfig);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <UserProvider>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </UserProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```